# Looking at clothing of a woman

Tags: women, clothing, sexuality

It says in Shulchan Aruch Evan HaEzer Siman 21 Sif 1 that it's ossur to look at the colored clothing of a woman that you know even if she is not wearing them, lest one come to "hirhurim" (to think about) that woman.

What about if someone's wife borrows a dress from her friend that you know, is it a problem then to look at one's wife when she is wearing that dress (or to specifically look at the dress.)

Comment: Are you thinking of your wife or her friend when you look at her? This is a completely subjective thing.

Comment: Perhaps it's also subjective the whole din...What about if when one sees clothing of a woman he knows he doesn't think about her, is it still a problem?

Comment: As a practical matter ask your wife not to tell you *who* she borrowed the dress from.

Comment: @Ariel Not so practical always